# Json post запрос python

Tags: python, json, post, requests

Можно ли через питон отправлять такой пост запрос:

```
user_info" : {
"username" : "<user login>",
"key" : "<api_key>"
},
{
...
}
```

Comment: У вас json неправильный )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это `json`, смотрите описание `api`, преобразуем и добавляем заголовок:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://domain.com'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',  # Определение типа данных
           'Accept': 'text/plain',
           'Content-Encoding': 'utf-8'}
data = {"user_info" : [{"username" : "<user login>",
                       "key" : "<api_key>"},
                      {}]}  # Если по одному ключу находится несколько словарей, формируем список словарей
answer = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print(answer)
response = answer.json()
print(response)
```

Comment: Если вместо `data=json.dumps(data)` указать `json=json`, то и заголовок `'Content-type': 'application/json'` не нужно указывать :) да и заголовок обычно для requests не нужно указывать -- он достаточно умный чтобы самому правильно заполнить его

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за уточнение, однако некоторые `api` требуют определенных заголовков и при их отсутствии отдают 4хх статус, мне кажется, нет ничего плохого в явном описание заголовка

Comment: Вот когда с таким требовательным вебсервером встретиться, тогда и указывать нехватающие ему заголовки :) у меня где-то был код, который выводил в консоль то, что requests отправляет при запросе и еще можно запрос на http://httpbin.org слать и смотреть что он вернул -- а это будет то, что ему пошлют. Так можно узнать, к примеру, какие и в каких случаях поля запроса были заполнены requests :)

Comment: @gil9red У меян `headers` вошло в привычку, за сервис спасибо, штука полезная ;)

Answer (score 7):

Отправить такой запрос можно с помощью `requests`:

```
import requests
response = requests.post('https://ru.stackoverflow.com', json={"key": "value"})
```